# JDBC connection to Sql Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have been writing **Java** applets using Eclipse and now I'd like to try some advanced elements like **JDBC Connection** to **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008**.
What driver should I install and where can I find it? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [Googleing it](https://www.google.com.eg/search?hl=ar&client=firefox-a&hs=YhB&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=rcs&q=JDBC+Connection+to+SQL+Server+2008&oq=JDBC+Connection+to+SQL+Server+2008&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i30i19j0i5i30i19j0i8i30i19l2j0i30i19.3074.3438.0.4012.2.2.0.0.0.0.205.391.0j1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.Ea4Ndergj1U), this is the first hit: [Connecting to SQL Server with the JDBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378672.aspx)

Comment: you may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480619/can-a-java-application-running-on-a-windows-server-connect-to-sql-server-via-wi/12519477#12519477 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496045/unable-to-connect-to-sqlexpress-using-jdbc-connection-refused-error/12496575#12496575 to get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the driver from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)

Answer (score 2):

u have to install Microsoft SQL Server2008 . u can get it from microsoft's websites
visit this link- [visit here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) and [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)